# Page layout URL back button?

Tags: visualforce, button

[image]I have a button on my account that opens a url into the page with sidebar and header.

the problem is business now wants to be able to go back to the account that they clicked the button from. they would essentially like a "back" button.

yes i know there is one built into the browser :(

I can only think of 1 option and that is changing the button to open up a VFP and inside that VFP use an iframe to display the webpage.

is there an easier solution? is there a solution that i am missing?

EDIT: for more clarification

image attached

account --> buttons, links, and actions --> new button or link

Comment: They can't just click "Cancel"? Could you please **[edit]** your post to include a minimum reproduction of what you've done so far?

Comment: there is no cancel button, let me see if i can add a picture. I haven't written any code yet nor done any changes. I don't need help with the coding aspect of this. I'm trying to think of a better solution than a VFP.

Comment: Well, without seeing what we're dealing with, I'm not sure we can provide an answer for you. You could at least include the button code?

Comment: picture uploaded, sorry for confusion

Comment: Don't link to external image hosting sites. Those images can be replaced or missing in the future. Theres a built in tool for hosting images available.